# JSON Parse (JSON Object Not Found) Java

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have a JSON file format in a variable called "json" that I want to parse. 
However, I'm getting this error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["bindings"] not found.
```

This is the code I'm using:

```
JSONObject obj =  new JSONObject(json);            
JSONArray bindings = obj.getJSONArray("bindings");       

for (int i=0; i<obj.length(); i++)
{
JSONObject x = bindings.getJSONObject(i);                
x.getJSONObject("type1").getString("type");  
System.out.println(x);
}
```

This is the JSON I'm trying to parse:

```
{
  "head": {
    "vars": [ "type1" , "pred" , "type2" ]
  } ,
  "results": {
    "bindings": [
      {
        "type1": { "type": "Collection" } ,
        "type2": { "type": "has" } ,
        "type3": { "type": "contributor" }
      } ,
      {
        "type1": { "type": "Collection2" } ,
        "type2": { "type": "has2" } ,
        "type3": { "type": "contributor2" }
      } 

]
}
}
```

Even when I execute the following without the for loop it keeps showing the same error msg.

```
JSONObject obj =  new JSONObject(json);            
JSONArray bindings = obj.getJSONArray("bindings");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass by the results `JSONObject` first in order to get to your `JSONArray`:

```
JSONObject obj =  new JSONObject(json);           
JSONObject results = obj.getJSONObject("results"); 
JSONArray bindings = results.getJSONArray("bindings");
```